# Visual Studio Mac Won't Accept User Input in the Built in Terminal

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to enter user input in the built in terminal on Visual Studio Mac but it doesn't allow me to. Is there a setting I need to change or something I need to set up?

```
using System;

public class Input
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is your name? ");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a terminal so it won't take your input. Please change project settings to use an external console.

Comment: An integrated Terminal is slated for a upcoming Visual Studio for Mac preview release: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/mac-roadmap#2020-q1-january-march